# Why doesn't labels(n) function return the correct count?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to count how many labels in my graph and execute the following:

```
match (n) return (count(labels(n)))
```

The count returned by this statement isn't the same as the count when I can see from the listed labels highlighted in different colors in the Browser. There are two more labels listed in the browser than the count returned by the function.

Why is that?

Comment: Your query does not return a count. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: @cybersam please see my editing. typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is getting the label collection for each node, and then counting how many collections there are, which is the same as the number of nodes.

To get a count of the number of labels in the DB, you can use the APOC procedure [apoc.meta.stats](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_meta_graph), which returns a variety of DB statistics. For your specific case, you can do this:

```
CALL apoc.meta.stats() YIELD labelCount
RETURN labelCount;
```

Comment: If you are asking about how to get the number of nodes for each label, then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48726836/how-to-count-the-numbers-of-node-types-in-the-neo4j-graph/48727993#48727993).

Comment: I tried the CALL command, but it returns 4 more node types than I actually have. I just want to get a count of all label types.

Comment: Yes, see my comments under his answer.

Comment: @user697911 If your DB has indices and/or constraints, then the label count can include their labels even though you do not actually have nodes with those labels. By the way: in neo4j terminology, nodes have "labels" and relationships have "types". The terms "label type" and "node type" should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

This cypher query will return a list of node labels and their counts:

```
match (n) return labels(n),count(n)
```

If you are seeking the count of a specific label, use

```
match (n:{your label}) return count(n)
```

If you want the count of the number of distinct labels:

```
match (n) with collect(distinct labels(n)) as NL return size(NL)
```

Comment: All of these queries are flawed. The [LABELS](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-labels) function returns a *collection* of labels, since nodes can have multiple labels. So the first and third queries will only work (somewhat) reasonably if all nodes in the DB have at most one label. The second query is using the older [parameter](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/parameters/) syntax for "your label", but parameters cannot be used as a label in a `MATCH` like that.

Comment: Correct, I did assume there was one label per node. The question did not suggest otherwise. There were other ambiguities in the question that suggested the other answers might be relevant. I used the {} incorrectly.